# High CPU, possibly due to context switching?

Tags: java, multithreading

One of our servers is experiencing a very high CPU load with our application. We've looked at various stats and are having issues finding the source of the problem.

One of the current theories is that there are too many threads involved and that we should try to reduce the number of concurrently executing threads. There's just one main thread pool, with 3000 threads, and a WorkManager working with it (this is Java EE - Glassfish). At any given moment, there are about 620 separate network IO operations that need to be conducted in parallel (use of java.NIO is not an option either). Moreover, there are roughly 100 operations that have no IO involved and are also executed in parallel.

This structure is not efficient and we want to see if it is actually causing damage, or is simply bad practice. Reason being that any change is quite expensive in this system (in terms of man hours) so we need some proof of an issue.

So now we're wondering if context switching of threads is the cause, given there are far more threads than the required concurrent operations. Looking at the logs, we see that on average there are 14 different threads executed in a given second. If we take into account the existence of two CPUs (see below), then it is 7 threads per CPU. This doesn't sound like too much, but we wanted to verify this.

So - can we rule out context switching or too-many-threads as the problem?

General Details:

1. Java 1.5 (yes, it's old), running on CentOS 5, 64-bit, Linux kernel 2.6.18-128.el5
2. There is only one single Java process on the machine, nothing else.
3. Two CPUs, under VMware.
4. 8GB RAM
5. We don't have the option of running a profiler on the machine.
6. We don't have the option of upgrading the Java, nor the OS.

**UPDATE**
As advised below, we've conducted captures of load average (using uptime) and CPU (using vmstat 1 120) on our test server with various loads. We've waited 15 minutes between each load change and its measurements to ensure that the system stabilized around the new load and that the load average numbers are updated:

50% of the production server's workload: http://pastebin.com/GE2kGLkk

34% of the production server's workload: http://pastebin.com/V2PWq8CG

25% of the production server's workload: http://pastebin.com/0pxxK0Fu

CPU usage appears to be reduced as the load reduces, but not on a very drastic level (change from 50% to 25% is not really a 50% reduction in CPU usage). Load average seems uncorrelated with the amount of workload.

There's also a question: given our test server is also a VM, could its CPU measurements be impacted by other VMs running on the same host (making the above measurements useless)?

**UPDATE 2**
Attaching the snapshot of the threads in three parts (pastebin limitations)

Part 1: http://pastebin.com/DvNzkB5z

Part 2: http://pastebin.com/72sC00rc

Part 3: http://pastebin.com/YTG9hgF5

Comment: Well what about reducing the number of threads in the thread pool and see if it helps?

Comment: High CPU usage can be good: it means that your utilization of the CPU resource is optimal. Your threads are computing something, not waiting for I/O or a lock. Unless you have a tight loop consuming your CPU needlessly, you should be happy about high level of concurrency that you managed to achieve.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight That's true if we manage to prove that there's no waste involved (such as context switching). If we manage to do that, we can tell the system team to add more CPUs and justify what it is so. But first, we have to do our homework.

Comment: @Voo That's a possibility which we'll add to the list.

Comment: @Voo Reducing the number of threads was tested in the test environment and didn't help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems to me the problem is 100 CPU bound threads more than anything else. 3000 thread pool is basically a red herring, as idle threads don't consume much of anything. The I/O threads are likely sleeping "most" of the time, since I/O is measured on a geologic time scale in terms of computer operations.

You don't mention what the 100 CPU threads are doing, or how long they last, but if you want to slow down a computer, dedicating 100 threads of "run until time slice says stop" will most certainly do it. Because you have 100 "always ready to run", the machine will context switch as fast as the scheduler allows. There will be pretty much zero idle time. Context switching will have impact because you're doing it so often. Since the CPU threads are (likely) consuming most of the CPU time, your I/O "bound" threads are going to be waiting in the run queue longer than they're waiting for I/O. So, even more processes are waiting (the I/O processes just bail out more often as they hit an I/O barrier quickly which idles the process out for the next one).

No doubt there are tweaks here and there to improve efficiency, but 100 CPU threads are 100 CPU threads. Not much you can do there.

Comment: Thank you for the insight. Looking at the thread stack posted in the second update to the question, what do you think?

Comment: After reviewing the thread stack and playing around with the thread pool size, etc., we've come to the conclusion that you are correct here. We haven't reduced the thread pool size but instead have changed some of the code so that tasks that require no I/O and do not wait on anything will be executed in serial. Other tasks are executed in parallel but have a certain limit to the number of tasks executed in parallel, based on our estimation of how many threads will be in the RUNNABLE state at any given moment.

Comment: Is the context switch time also included in the CPU utilization??

Answer (score 4):

I think your constraints are unreasonable. Basically what you are saying is:

```
1.I can't change anything
2.I can't measure anything
```

Can you please speculate as to what my problem might be?

The real answer to this is that you need to hook a proper profiler to the application and you need to correlate what you see with CPU usage, Disk/Network I/O,  and memory.

Remember the 80/20 rule of performance tuning. 80% will come from tuning your application. You might just have too much load for one VM instance and it could be time to consider solutions for scaling horizontally or vertically by giving more resources to the machine. It could be any one of the 3 billion JVM settings are not inline with your application's execution specifics.

I assume the 3000 thread pool came from the famous more threads = more concurrency = more performance theory. The real answer is a tuning change isn't worth anything unless you measure throughput and response time before/after the change and compared the results.

Comment: The rationale behind our inability to do things is that the server is behind several protective measures, on the other side of the planet. We need to fly there and even then it has no Internet access so things are quite cumbersome. We really prefer not to do that. Giving more resources requires convincing the local system team, which means we need evidence.

Comment: The thread pool came from this: the number of concurrent IO tasks can grow without us controlling it, there is someone else (call him Operator) who can cause this increase with little understanding of the system. So, we set 3000 as the number which should be sufficient for any amount of work this Operator can throw at the system. The problem with thread pools in Glassfish is apparently they cannot be resized at runtime.

Comment: Your justification is completely invalid. The thread pool size is not an allowance you give your child. Why not just set it to 4 billion? It is an indicator to your application as to its physical operating environment and the limitations there in. Finding the right number is a trial and error process. To little and work will queue and cores will sit idle, too much the cost of switching between threads outwieghs to benefits of concurrent execution. You need to use the power of Science to find the right number

Comment: It needs to be adjusted automatically, with zero human involvement. How do you recommend we go about doing that?

Comment: @Yon It does not. If your application runs best with X threads on your hardware, it does run best with X threads and not 2X. If the code has to run on lots of different hardware it's best to approximate the best number wrt the number of cores the machine has. 1-2.5 times the cores is usually a good bet for CPU intense tasks, if there's lots of IO going on increase it. But 1:1500 seems like orders of magnitude off target.. but who knows without measuring it?

Comment: @Voo Would the following guideline make sense: 1-2.5 times number of cores PLUS number of anticipated concurrent IO operations?

Comment: @Yon there is no universally applicable number, your number of threads will most likely be specific to your environment.

Answer (score 2):

> So - can we rule out context switching or too-many-threads as the problem?

I think you concerns over thrashing are warranted.  A thread pool with 3000 threads (700+ concurrent operations) on a 2 CPU VMware instance *certainly* seems like a problem that may be causing context switching overload and performance problems.  Limiting the number of threads *could* give you a performance boost although determining the right number is going to be difficult and probably will use a lot of trial and error.

> we need some proof of an issue.

I'm not sure the best way to answer but here are some ideas:

- Watch the load average of the VM OS and the JVM.  If you are seeing high load values (20+) then this is an indicator that there are too many things in the run queues.
- Is there no way to simulate the load in a test environment so you can play with the thread pool numbers?  If you run simulated load in a test environment with pool size of X and then run with X/2, you should be able to determine optimal values.
- Can you compare high load times of day with lower load times of day?  Can you graph number of responses to latency during these times to see if you can see a tipping point in terms of thrashing?
- If you can simulate load then make sure you aren't just testing under the "drink from the fire hose" methodology.  You need simulated load that you can dial up and down.  Start at 10% and slowing increase simulated load while watching throughput and latency.  You should be able to see the tipping points by watching for throughput flattening or otherwise deflecting.

Comment: To add to the mix here, the number of CPUs may be changed by the system team without our control, so we need something that re-tunes every boot.

Comment: @Yon It seems to me that you are orders of magnitude off here in terms of threads to physical cores so I don't think 1 or 2 extra CPUs configured at boot is going to make a difference.  Have you tried running the system on a 8 or 16 CORE system somewhere?

Comment: How do we prove your assertion and justify the work involved?

Comment: @Yon I've added a proof section to my answer.

Comment: @Yon Do you work in insanity land? I can't look at the box, I can't make any changes, The operators can make arbitrary changes without warning or justification. Sounds like your problems are organizational not technical. Move your app the the cloud.

Comment: @Gray Good expansion. The load average is usually in the lower teens (10-15). In our test server, which handles roughly half the work of this production server, CPU hangs around 50% and load average is about 10. Changing the size of the thread pool there (from 3000 to 500, for example) has no impact. There are no peak times in this environment, load is steady.

Comment: @Gray - yes, I can't tell whether this box is suffering from excessive context-changes or is simply showing syptoms of being grossly overloaded.  An average of 14 ready threads on a 2-core box is a big overload but, how much of this time is spent on switching is unclear becasue we don't know how much useful work is done by the average work item when it is run by a pool thread compared with the time taken to switch to another thread.

Comment: @Yon Are you loading your test server under the "drink from a fire hose" methodology?  If so then you need to redesign your simulated load.  What happens to performance as you ramp up load?  Start at 10% and then increase the load slowly watching latency and overall throughput.  You should be able to see tipping points when throughput flattens out or otherwise deflects.

Comment: @MartinJames Based on log4j logging done by threads during the work load, the average time slot for a thread is a few milliseconds. Makes sense?

Comment: @Gray Updated the question to include measurements run over the past hour or so on our test server based on your comment.

Comment: @Yon 'the average time slot for a thread is a few milliseconds' - OK, if this is the run time, not run+ switch-time, your environment is just overloaded.  You should try faster/more CPU's.  If VM only allows 2 'processors', (my VMware workstation only alllows 2, even though the host has 4+4HT), then, as another poster suggested, try running outside the VM, if only as a trial.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't profile, I'd recommend taking a thread dump or two and seeing what your threads are doing.  Your app doesn't have to stop to do it:

1. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/threads.html
2. http://java.net/projects/tda/
3. http://java.sys-con.com/node/1611555

Answer (score 1):

Usually, context switching in threads is very cheap computationally, but when it involves this many threads... you just can't know. You say upgrading to Java 1.6 EE is out of the question, but what about some hardware upgrades ? It would probably provide a quick fix and shouldn't be that expensive...

Comment: The system team requires evidence from us to explain why any change in resources is justified.

Answer (score 0):

e.g. run a profiler on a similar machine.

- try a newer version of Java 6 or 7. (It may not make a difference, in which case don't bother upgrading production)
- try Centos 6.x
- try not using VMware.
- try reducing the number of threads. You only have 8 cores.

You many find all or none of the above options make a difference, but you won't know until you have a system you can test on with a known/repeatable work load.

Comment: We have a test environment running roughly half the load. Changing Java versions had no impact on it, nor was reducing the number of threads.

Comment: So you could conclude that upgrading the version of Java won't help and the number of threads is probably not a problem.

Comment: One of the questions we have is: is there a possibility where more loaded servers are waking up more threads and this context switching is causing the problem? It's important to remember that even with larger pools, most of the threads are waiting on a queue.

Comment: If the server is busy it can slow down the application dramatically. esp if it has to compete for CPU, memory or IO (e.g. disk or network)  If it is doing this it should be obvious, in `top` or Task Manager.