# Java using more memory than allocated

Tags: java, multithreading, memory, synchronization, stack-overflow

I was testing a few things in Java this morning, and I ran this piece of code, expecting aN `OutOfMemoryError`:

```
public class SynchronizedSpammer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while (true) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    syncWait();
                }
            }).start();
        }
    }

    public static synchronized void syncWait() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100000L);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

To my surprise, my computer crashed several seconds after it used up all the memory and swap.

This works too:

```
public class Crash {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while (true) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(10000L);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }).start();
        }
    }
}
```

What has happened?  Why isn't the memory limited by the Xmx?

Comment: How precisely did you determine that "it used up all the memory and swap"? What exactly did you observe?

Comment: I ran `top` in a shell and saw the memory and swap usage increase to 100%, before freezing everything.

Comment: You're specifying heap size not stack size.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`StackOverflowError` will get thrown if a thread's stack is full (too many local variable, or function calls).

Your threads are not doing much so they are not filling up their stacks, so you are not getting `StackOverflowError`. You are running out of memory because you are creating too many threads and each thread does occupy some amount of memory (it needs memory for its stack).

If you really want to get `StackOverflowError` what you can do is set -Xss 104k (104 kilo bytes stack size) and:

```
public class StackEater{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                   public void run() {
                      printLevel(1);
                   }});
    t.start();
    t.join()
    }

    public static void printLevel(long n) {

        System.out.println(n);
        printLevel(n+1);

    }
}
```

Compare the largest number with:

```
public class StackEater{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                   public void run() {
                      printLevel(1, 1);
                   }});
        t.start();
        t.join()
    }

    public static void printLevel(long n, long m) {

        System.out.println(n);
        printLevel(n+1, m+1);

    }
}
```

You will see that the second example will print out smaller n before throwing exception, because it is using more stack space by taking in additional argument.

Comment: The problem is that my program just exceeds the memory I gave it.

Comment: If you specify using Xmx JVM can use more memory than you specified. Xmx sets heap size. Creating thread occupies "system memory" that is not part of the heap. So the number of threads you can create is not limited by Xmx, but by how much memory you have on your system (or limit by how OS manage threads).

Comment: Do you have a reference for that? What is this "system memory"?

Comment: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2013/01/difference-between-stack-and-heap-java.html

Comment: I don't think this is related at all. None of the threads created exceed their stack space. And the number of threads created would eventually cause the heap to run out of space. This is a CPU issue.

Comment: You mean in my example? In my example I exceed the stack space by doing non-terminating recursion (hence the StackOverFlowError). In the original example, the threads are not using enough stack space so you run out of memory before you run out of stack.

Comment: No, I mean in OP's @Runemoro code. There is no stack overflow. OP says that their computer crashes. This is because the CPU usage jumps to 100%. It has nothing to do with the memory allocated to the Java process.

Comment: "I ran top in a shell and saw the memory and swap usage increase to 100%, before freezing everythin" that's what OP said :)

Answer (score 2):

You are creating too many `Thread` objects!

```
while (true) {
   new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            syncWait();
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Do you mean this?

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            syncWait();
        }
    }
}).start();
```

Comment: But why does it exceed the `Xmx` I gave it? If I would just create objects and store them in a list (to stop them from being GC'd) it would reach an `OutOfMemoryError`.

Comment: No, I didn't mean the second. I wanted to see what would happen when I kept calling a synchronized method, I didn't expect java to use more than it's allocated memory.

Comment: @Runemoro What do you expect it to do when it reaches its max?

Comment: Xmx is specifies the max heap size. Heap is use to store objects. When you create thread you will occupy system memory that's not part of heap try to give bigger Xss and you will see your program crash with fewer threads.

Comment: @Runemoro The second is just the code that kept calling a synchronized method.You are creating too many object that can not be collected so the Xmx is exceeded.

Comment: So it's normal for java to use all my 8gb of memory when it has only been given 128MB?

Comment: @Runemoro What evidence do you have that it is using all 8gb?

Comment: @Runemoro NONONO,OutOfMemoryError is thrown when your program exceed the 128MB,not the whole 8GB.

Comment: I was expecting that to happen, but that's not what happens. Run it and watch your computer crash.

Comment: I have tried this code in my computer,nothing happened except some error log.

Answer (score 1):

You would run out of heap space before you ran out of stack space.

The issue here is that you are creating and starting a lot of threads. All the threads block at the `syncWait()` call but until they get there, the thread scheduler is busy context switching. That, in addition to the infinite `while` loop, overloads the CPU.

This does not start as a memory issue, although that's how it would end.

Here's some related reading:

- [Could context switch cause high CPU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18941338/could-context-switch-cause-high-cpu)
- [High CPU, possibly due to context switching?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9535135/high-cpu-possibly-due-to-context-switching)

Comment: But it doesn't throw an error (atleast on my computer), it just exceeds the memory it was given.

Comment: @Runemoro Edited. It's a CPU problem. There's too much context switching between threads.

Comment: Unlikely CPU problem, because the spawned threads are sleeping most of the time.

Comment: @Alvin It's not only the threads, it's the `while(true)`. And it isn't about the sleeping threads, it's about all the newly created ones. The process is creating them faster than it can context switch.

Comment: Oh yes, you are right about the while(true), I missed that.